# Filter array of object from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two arrays. I want to filter one array which contains objects from another array.

```
let array1= [{date:1, count:4}, {date:3, count:6}];
let array2= [1,2,3,4];
```

After filtering these two arrays, I need filtered arrays as below.

```
let array= [4,0,6,0];
```

So, the filtered array contains the count for matched date and zero for unmatched values. But I'm getting only matched data.

Here is my code:

```
let array = _.map(_.filter(array1, function(o){
    return _.includes(array2, o.date);
}), 'count');
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `find()` methods for this. You don't need `filter()` because for each element you will return count or 0 so you can just use `map()`.

```js
let array1= [{date:1, count:4}, {date:3, count:6}];
let array2= [1,2,3,4];

var array = array2.map(function(e) {
  var f = array1.find(a => a.date == e);
  return f ? f.count : 0
});

console.log(array)
```